# How to fail an Ansible task if the underlying Powershell script it runs, fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, ansible, aws-ssm

I am running 'aws ssm send-command' to trigger a powershell script on a remote windows host using Ansible. I want this Ansible task to fail if the powershell script fails. This is what my code looks like but it doesn't seem to work.

```
**name**: Run SSM command
**shell**: aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --document-version "1" \--targets "Key=instanceids,Values={{ instances | join(',') }}" \--parameters '{{ parameters | to_json | safe }}' \--timeout-seconds 300 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0
**vars**: <passing variables>
**register**: result
**failed_when**: result.rc != 0
```

I have made some changes to my powershell script for it to fail, and it does. But the return code never gets passed on to Ansible.

I have also tried the 'if' statement as suggested by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/command-exit-codes.html, but it did not work for me.

Could someone please advise what am I doing wrong here. As said, I want the Ansible task to fail if the powershell script it runs, fails. I cannot use win_shell ansible module coz the installation this powershell script does, fails when used with winrm, hence using aws ssm.

Comment: "does not seem to work", "did not work for me" are not accurate descriptions of the exact behavior you are observing, the debug steps you have already taken, the code you wrote in your PowerShell nor the errors which are fired. Please read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve). Note: falling when rc is not 0 is the default for shell module. I suspect the AWS cmd is swallowing your script rc a way or an other.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Anyway, I have figured it out. The rc for my aws command was always 0 coz it always successfully runs the powershell script. The error originating from the powershell command had to be handled inside another command, which when passed to Ansible - fails as expected.